# 2d Tiled Map with images in Javascript

Tags: 2d, javascript, tiles

I'm trying to create a tile map with simple 2d images (30x30). I restarted the project from my previous post, and instead of using someone else's code, i though I would learn more to start from scratch. It was going well, but I ran into a bump when attempting to use images for tiles. My previous project used to following to create simple cubes. Now I'm trying to use images, and was wondering if there is a way to make the images wihtout having to follow the exact same steps as below:

```
function renderLevel(){
// clear the canvas
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// walls = red boxes
context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
for(i=0;i<levelRows;i++){
    for(j=0;j<levelCols;j++){
        if(level[i][j]==1){
            blockrow.push(i);
            blockcol.push(j);
            context.fillRect(j*tileSize,i*tileSize,tileSize,tileSize);
            console.log("add");
            //collision[i] = new Array ([i],[j]);
        }
    }
}
// player = green box
context.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
context.fillRect(playerXPos,playerYPos,tileSize,tileSize);
```

}

Currently, I'm trying to simply drop the images, and manually declare the sizes when calling them.

```
    function setmapimages(){
    for (i=0;i<mapArray.length; i++){
        for (k=0; k<mapArray[i].length; k++){
            //image for player
            if (k==positionX && i==positionY){
                ctx.drawImage(img, 30, 30);
            }
            //image for road
            if (mapArray[i][k] == 0){
                ctx.drawImage(img2, 30, 30);
            }
            //image for collision
            if (mapArray[i][k] == 1){
                ctx.drawImage(img3, 30, 30);
            }
            //image for Store
            if (mapArray[i][k] == 2){
                ctx.drawImage(img4, 30, 30);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I set the canvas size similarly to the previous project:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width =img.width*11;
canvas.height =img.height*9;
```

Although I set the variables a bit different. Since I'm using images now.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src= "image.png";
var img2 = new Image();
img.src= "image2.png";
var img3 = new Image();
img.src= "image3.png";
var img4 = new Image();
img.src= "image3.png";
```

Am I calling the images correctly? I looked up "drawimage" and think I went the wrong way with this, but I'm unsure what could call the images correctly.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation for the different file formats tiled uses](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/reference/json-map-format/)? These describe everything you need to know about the tiles. It tells you which id belongs to which image

Answer (score 1):

First off, I have a comment about how you are creating your images. It is probably going to be easier for you to make a function and call it instead of manually setting everything like you're doing. Ex:

```
function imageConstruct(url) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = url;
  return image;
} // USAGE: var img = imageConstruct("my_cat.png");
```

Now on to the meat of your question.

Are you getting any errors that you need me to solve, or are you just wondering if your current method of creating the tile level is valid? I always use a spritesheet now, which requires a bit of different math, but I used separate images like you while I was learning. Since spritesheets are a separate topic, I'll stick to what you're doing.

The way you've set up your `for` loops for the 2d array looks good to me, but notice how each iteration you're running 3 if statements no matter what. Even if its tile 0, you check if its a 1 or 2 after, which is not as efficient as you can make it. I suggest using a `switch` statement like I will model below, or `if...else if... else` because once the tile is found to be 0, 1, or 2, it won't keep checking :)

For the best performance, the tile that appears most often in your map should be the 1st case and the tile that appears the least should be the last case so each loop executes faster with less value checking.

Your current code doesn't look like it displays a grid, it looks like each tile is getting rendered at x: 30, y: 30. If you do `ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);` the image will be rendered at its default width and height because you aren't specifying it. Since your images are all 30x30, that's not a problem for you right now, but your code above won't create a grid because you need to calculate each tile's x and y position and render it there instead of rendering them all at 30 30. `ctx.drawImage(image, i*30, k*30);` will render each tile at the correct x and y position. You have that same calculation in your first code snippet, so I assume that you know how it works, but if you want me to explain it, I can.

ex:

```
switch(mapArray[i][k]) {
  case 0:
    ctx.drawImage(img, k*30, i*30);
    break;
  case 1:
    ctx.drawImage(img1, k*30, i*30);
    break;
  //etc.
}
```

You can change i and k in your loops to y and x if that's easier for you to read.

Please let me know if you have any other questions or if I didn't understand everything you were asking!